# How to order by certain columns first in a union select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am doing a `SELECT` statement from various tables, but I want to `ORDER BY` a set of criteria first. Here is an example of the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT
 a.ItemName,
 a.ItemDescription,
 a.ItemPrice,
 a.DateAdded,
 a.UserID,
 u.UserType
FROM
 table a
 inner join user u ON
 u.UserID = a.UserID
UNION
SELECT
 b.ItemName,
 b.ItemDescription,
 b.ItemPrice,
 b.DateAdded,
 b.UserID,
 u.UserType
FROM
 table b
 inner join user u ON
 u.UserID = b.UserID
UNION
SELECT
 c.ItemName,
 c.ItemDescription,
 c.ItemPrice,
 c.DateAdded,
 c.UserID,
 u.UserType
FROM
 table c
inner join user u ON
u.UserID = c.UserID
```

From the above resultset, I would like to first `ORDER BY where u.UserType = 'Consultant' and DateAdded DESC, and then by u.UserType = 'Internal' and Price DESC and DateAdded DESC`.

How could I force the *sorting* in the above manner?

Comment: On a side note: It would be strange for a real database to have multiple item tables, but that's just an example I guess? And are there really duplicates to remove? Otherwise use `UNION ALL` to spare the DBMS the unecessary work.

Comment: They are different tables, but all contain different types of items. When I'm doing the UNION I just alias all the columns so they match up. For example it would actually be `SELECT c.MonroeProductCode AS ItemDescription` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `case`

```
Order by
       case when u.UserType = 'Consultant' then 1 else 0 end,
       DateAdded desc,
       case when u.UserType = 'Internal' then 1 else 0 end,
       Price desc,
       DateAdded desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any DDL and Sample data to test on, this is a bit of a guess, but perhaps...

```
ORDER BY CASE UserType WHEN 'Consultant' THEN 1 END DESC,
         DateAdded DESC,
         CASE UserType WHEN 'Internal' THEN 1 END DESC,
         Price DESC,
         DateAdded DESC;
```

Edit, upon rereading, I'm not entirely sure this is what the OP wants. Sample and expected output would be useful if myself and Magnus are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First order by consultant or not. Then order by price (but not for consultants, so for them order by a constant pseudo price). Then order by date added.

```
order by
  case when usertype = 'Consultant' then 1 else 2 end,
  case when usertype = 'Consultant' then 0 else price end desc,
  dateadded desc;
```

This has consultants first (ordered by date added), followed by all others (ordered by price and date added).

If there exist more user types than just the two you have mentioned and you want consultants first, then internals, then others, you'd have to change the first order line accordingly:

```
order by
  case usertype when 'Consultant' then 1 when 'Internal' then 2 else 3 end,
  case when usertype = 'Consultant' then 0 else price end desc,
  dateadded desc;
```

Comment: Yes there are more than just Consultant and Internal. How come your case statement check on when `usertype = 'Consultant'` more than once? Doesn't that mean that it will be true in both cases? Could you explain what is the difference of `then 0` compared with `then 1`. I don't understand the numbering system exactly.

Comment: We want to have all consultants first, then all internals. This is what the first line in `ORDER BY` does; it checks what usertype the row is and gives it a sort number 1 for consultants, 2 for internals, 3 for others. Once this is done, we get to the second line. So inside consultants and inside internals etc. we sort further. As there is only one `ORDER BY` clause per query, however, we must find a sort order that is good for all usertypes...

Comment: ... Let's look at consultants: if we detect a consultant row we give it a constant sort value 0 (this could be any constant value). So no consultant is better than the other, no sorting is done. For other usertypes, however, we use the price for their sort value, so the block of internals get sort further by price. Then the last line where we order by date added: The block of consultants comes first, but the consultants themselves are unordered and get ordered by date now...

Comment: The block of internals comes next. Internals are ordered by price already and now those with the same price get ordered by date. If you still don't understand it: use Excel. Columns: sortkey1, sortkey2, sortkey3, usertype, price, dateadded. Have some consultants and internals with different and same prices and dates (say, some twenty rows). Make sortkey1 = 1 for consultants, 2 for internals, 3 else. Make sortkey2 = 0 for consultants, price for other. Make sortkey3 the date. Sort by sortkey1 alone. See what you get. Sort by sortkey1 and sortkey2. Sort by sortkey1 and sortkey2 and sortkey3.